# Is it correct English by "all them long words"

Tags: phrase-usage

I came across this sentence in Oxford dictionary on my phone. Here is the entry from [Oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anyways):

> anyways
>   adverb
>   North American
>   informal, dialect
>   ‘you wouldn't understand **all them long words** anyways’

I feel **all them long words** isn't correct. Instead, **all those long words** looks more correct to me. But as it's in the dictionary, I have to give it the benefit of the doubt.

Is it really correct?

Comment: "All them" is slang only. "All those" is correct, although I'm in the camp that prefers "all **of** those."

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary is somewhat misleading in labeling this a North American usage. Characters in Dickens novels say "anyways" and "all them" too.  ELL 
regular @tetsujin IIRC would probably know if it is used in northern England.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This non-standard usage of 'them' comes from [African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), earlier known as Ebonics (a controversial term).

You can also find the usage of 'them' instead of 'those/these' in titles of some old folk songs, e. g. *When You Hear Them Cuckoos Hollerin'* by Joan Baez or there's a song by Slade (who often intentionally used non-standard language) called *Them Kinda Monkeys Can't Swing*.

Comment: This is not necessarily AAVE. https://books.google.com/books?id=Oi01AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22anyways%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV-KuQ9LLdAhXvdN8KHeC7DuYQ6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q=%22anyways%22&f=false

Comment: Or https://books.google.com/books?id=4qtKAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%22all+them%22+Dickens&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsz6r59LLdAhXHkZAKHS-tDmgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22all%20them%22%20Dickens&f=false

Comment: I don't say 'originate', I say 'come (from)' (into modern language). It is a known thing that some origins of AAVE are in _old English_ which came to America with old editions of Holy Bible used in summer schools for teaching some groups of population (incl. former slaves) in the past.

Comment: People from various parts of England settled in the US and brought their regional dialects with them. The sentence in the OP could come just as readily out of the mouth of a white southerner.